# DRBD node 2 doesn't become primary when node 1 restarts heartbeat but becomes Secondary/Secondary

Tags: mysql, high-availability, ubuntu-18.04, drbd, heartbeat

I have an issue with heartbeat & drbd deployment for MySQL with 2 nodes on ubuntu 18.4.
It used to work fine, but now it seems like its working, node1 has floating IP, MySQL runs on node1,drbd syncs, but when I restart heartbeat on node1, node2 doesn't take primary but it switches to secondary/secondary until node1 can become primary again.
The full configuration is set according to [this tutorial.](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-drbd-heartbeat-high-availability/)
To better show you when I run `service heartbeat restart` on node 1 it goes from this:

```
version: 8.4.10 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 15111D056BF899E7D986DDD 
 0: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:3423796 nr:5756516 dw:317824672 dr:121706 al:2638 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

to this

```
version: 8.4.10 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 15111D056BF899E7D986DDD 
 0: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:3423968 nr:5756516 dw:317824844 dr:121706 al:2638 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

The desired outcome should be that node2 becomes primary until something goes wrong and node1 needs to become primary again.

Comment: Using Heartbeat as described in the link you shared, with the haresources file, has been deprecated for a very very long time. Any modern deployment of the Linux HA stack should be using Corosync and Pacemaker in place of Heartbeat v1.

Comment: @MattKereczman thank you for your response but I do not have the option of changing this setup at this time. I used to work for a long time until administrator in charge of management migrated VM's onto different Hyper-V clusters without switching them off, and something messed up.
Is there a way to fix it? Thanks